# Codekit, LESS CSS, Which files to upload?

Tags: css, less, codekit

So I'm using Codekit to compile LESS CSS on my local server. Now I need to transfer the files to my live server.

My question is, do I need to upload all the .less files? Or can I just upload the minified css file?

What is the best practice here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't plan on editing anything on your live server (which you shouldn't anyway), you only need to upload the compiled `.css` file; the compiled CSS is completely independent of the source LESS.

Comment: Furthermore, your web app won't load any resources that you don't actually link to. You could just as well upload your `.less` files, it doesn't matter in the slightest.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to upload CSS files.

Firstly, LESS might not be compatible for all browsers and secondly, CSS is your output of LESS file will take up some time(minimal but why to force on client) to compile it on run time.

Answer (score 0):

I am deploying files to a server from more than one machine, so I tend to upload (in my case) scss files (although less files are essentially similar) and then I can pull them down to a separate machine for editing. But the pages only refer to the css files.

As a minimum you only need to upload the compiled css file(s).